# How to save multiple (paperclip ) images into a rails model attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, paperclip, froala

I am trying to use a WYSIWYG editor like Froala to upload images to my server. The issue is I need to store multiple images into one attribute of the model. This is because I wont know ahead of time how many images will to be stored when my users upload images.

Would be great if anybody can give me some pointers. Or examples.

Comment: thanks for the responses, i got it now!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and search for `has_many`. You need an extra model which stores the images and which has an `other_model_id` attribute which points to the other model.

If you have never worked with `has_many` you'll find an example application at http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/activerecord_has_many.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have to save several images related to a model, you'll need an 1 - N relation.
So you have two choices:

1. Create a model like album and make an 1 - 1 relationship
2. Use an has_many (1-N) relationship.

To learn more about associations I really recommend you to read the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: If I create a model like user album (1-1 relationship), what data type do I use to keep all the images for one album?

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  #use paper clip for the following method
  has_attached_file :attachment
end
```

Now upload the images using your WYSIWYG editor, and append [nested images form](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) to the user form, submit the form and you are good to go. Hope this helps.